How to handle empty Enum Values for JsonParser
I have an spring boot project which parses a huge json file. Therefore I use the json parser (streaming-api) to get the objects one after one and read it to proper object when the size fits (parser.readValueAs(MyClass.class);. For the too large objects the nested elements are ignored and later read one by one.
I get an error while parsing an object which containing an empty string for a enumeration.
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot coerce empty String ("") to `com.example.enumeration.SortTarget` value (but could if coercion was enabled using 

CoercionConfig`)
Problem is that I found numerous examples how to do this with ObjectMapper but not with JsonParser, I tried
        try (JsonParser parser = factory.createParser(inputFile)) {
            parser.configure(JsonParser.Feature.XXX, true);

but cannot find the Feature needed that is the equavalent to DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_EMPTY_STRING_AS_NULL_OBJECT or find a proper example on how to use the CoercionConfig class similar to here or on the jackson-databind github page.
Any hint or link to the documentation would be helpful, Thanks.
Matt
